# Question regarding the potential method for amortized analysis

Tags: algorithm-analysis, amortized-analysis

What does the following mean exactly for the potential method? Is this applicable to all situations?

> If the potential is positive, then we overcharged for some operations.
>   If it is negative, we are undercharged.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Can you edit the question to include your understanding so far and what aspects of the potential method you do understand, so we can tailor answers to your level of understanding?  Note that the potential method is explained in many places, so there's little point in re-explaining it from scratch -- but if you can identify a specific question about some specific aspect that has you confused, and help us understand what specifically confuses you, it's likely that we can help.

Answer (score 2):

In the potential method, operation $O$, which has real cost (say time complexity) $p(O)$ is charged $c(O)$. The *potential* at any given point is $$\sum_{t=1}^T (c(O_t) - p(O_t)),$$ where $O_1,\ldots,O_T$ is a list of the operations that have been performed. The idea of the potential method is that if the potential is always non-negative then $$\sum_{t=1}^t p(O_t) \leq \sum_{t=1}^t c(O_t),$$ that is, we can bound the total real cost by the total amount of charge.

Hopefully now you can answer your question on your own.